# обработка последнего присланного сообщения telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Хочу присваивать переменной текст, который присылает пользователь

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['add'])
def handle_start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите ссылку на товар", disable_notification=True)
    url = message.text
    constants.items.append(url)
```

Но проблема в том, что в переменную записывается команда /add, а не отправленный текст.. Как поступить в данном случае?

Comment: `measage.split(maxsplit=1)[1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такая функция `bot.register_next_step_handler(message, another_process)`
В данном случае ***another_process*** это название функции в которой вы пишете что делать с отправленным текстом

```
def another_process(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ссылка на товар ' + message.text)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['add'])
def handle_start(message):
    message = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите ссылку на товар", disable_notification=True)
    url = message.text
    constants.items.append(url)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, another_process)
```